# Very Basic textView Problem in my Kotlin Code

Tags: android, kotlin

I just started learning Kotlin and decided to write a very basic programm. It's supposed to be a currency converter, but for now, I just want to give out the number I type into "editTextEingabe" ("Eingabe" = german for input) to the textView "textViewAusgabe". I'll link my code below and would be very happy if someone could help me with that. Thanks!

P.S.: "editTextEingabe" is set to be only allowing numbers and decimals to be enterd, but I don't know if that changes anything.

Update 2: The problem is, that the decimal number I type into editTextEingabe isn't appearing in textViewAusgabe after In press the Button buttonBerechnen. More simple: I want to give out text (here: A number) that I just typed into an editText to a textView widget, but that doesn't work.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var eingabe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEingabe)
        var eingabeString: String = eingabe.toString()
        var ergebnis: String
        val buttonBerechnen: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonBerechnen)

        buttonBerechnen.setOnClickListener() {
            ergebnis = eingabeString
            textViewAusgabe.text = ("$ergebnis")
        }

    }
}
```

Update: Here's my XML, if that helps:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAusgabe"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:background="#4600BCD4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEingabe"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:background="#4600BCD4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$ eingeben"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
        android:text="$ = "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextEingabe"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:text="€"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewAusgabe"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBerechnen"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:background="#4600BCD4"
        android:text="Berechnen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: 1. What's the behavior currently, is the text just not being updated when you press the button? 2. Have you tried running your code through the debugger? Can you put a breakpoint inside `setOnClickListener` and check what the value of `eingabe.text` is?

Comment: 1. There is text addet to textViewAusgabe, but it's just nonsense android text ("androidx.appcompact.widgetAppCompactEd..") everytime I press the button
2. I did, but it didn't gave me any useful information, at least not for me
3. What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you use the variables `ergebnis` and `eingabeString` to set the text of the `TextView`, but these variables are declared inside the `onCreate()` method and their values are probably empty strings and they never change.
 
Since you have this import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

you don't have to use `findViewById()` to get references to your widgets.
You can simplify your code to this:

```
buttonBerechnen.setOnClickListener() {
    textViewAusgabe.text = editTextEingabe.text.toString()
}
```

and remove all these variable declarations:

```
var eingabe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEingabe)
var eingabeString: String = eingabe.toString()
var ergebnis: String
val buttonBerechnen: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonBerechnen)
```

Comment: This worked very well. However, since this is intendet to be a curency converter when it's finished, I need to keep the variables. Can you tell me why it's not working my way besides beeing to complicated?

Comment: I edited my answer with a brief explanation.`eingabeString` is just a string and its value is  set inside onCreate() so it gets only 1 value which never changes. So when you type something in the EditText you don't reassign the text to this variable which then sets the text of the TextView. Anyway you don't need all these variables. Directly set the text of the TextView from the EditText.

Comment: So I've put "eingabe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEingabe).toString()" inside the setOnClickListener, but still, it doesn't do anything. You're right that I can remove a lot of it, but since I need those variables when continuing with my project, I need to know how it works with them too

Comment: If you need these variables then you must declare them in the class level and not inside onCreate. Also, the correct way to get that text is: `editTextEingabe.text.toString()`

Comment: I think I've made it with your last comment, thanks! And did I accept the answer correctly?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `eingabe.toString()` you're capturing the current input value of `eingabe` at the time of the call and assigning it to `eingabeString`. Anything that happens with the input value of `eingabe` after that will not be reflected on `eingabeString`. Hence when the `OnClickListener` fires, your code won't grab the up-to-date value from `eingabe`, but will instead use the stale value saved in `eingabeString`. An easy way to fix it in my opinion is to get rid of `eingabeString` completely and always reference the input value from `eingabe` when assigning it to `ergebnis`:

```
var eingabe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEingabe)
var ergebnis: String
buttonBerechnen: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonBerechnen)

buttonBerechnen.setOnClickListener() { 
    ergebnis = eingabe.toString()
    textViewAusgabe.text = ("$ergebnis")
}
```

*Removed Edit*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Like the other comment, this doesn't seem to help though. May the problem be, that I didn't get the conversion from the decimal number I type into the editText to the String I need for the textView?

Comment: Btw. I just saw that I edited your comment, not my original post. I'm really sorry for that, I must missclicked something

Comment: @KenzoVolgmann, no worries, thanks for fixing that - I approved your edit. I'd suggest that you clarify what the problem actually is in your question: it wasn't clear to me so I assumed you're not getting the up-to-date input field contents when the button is clicked. Happy to help once you clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to retrieve the value of the EditText in the click event.

Update  your code to :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var eingabe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEingabe)
        var ergebnis = ""
        val buttonBerechnen: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonBerechnen)

        buttonBerechnen.setOnClickListener() {
            ergebnis = eingabe.text.toString()
            textViewAusgabe.text = ("$ergebnis")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Like the other comment, this doesn't seem to help though. May the problem be, that I didn't get the conversion from the decimal number I type into the editText to the String I need for the textView?